# How to deal with a semicolon ";" in a string comparison?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am writing a Hive query and I need to compare a PIN (col) to a string value. The pin is encrypted and the encrypted value contains special characters.
I need to select all the rows with PIN containing this encrypted value.

For Example,
`select * from prod_db.prod_table where pin='ab;xzh[Ge';`

This is causing `;` to be read as a delimiter and causes `<EOF>` error.

Is there a way to deal with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using beeline? I'm asking this because in Hive CLI (old one) \\; works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace semicolon with `\073` or try double slash `\\;` to escape semicolon:

```
select * from prod_db.prod_table where pin='ab\073xzh[Ge';
```

or

```
select * from prod_db.prod_table where pin='ab\\;xzh[Ge';
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just one value that you are trying to compare then use the '\' to escape the special character.

```
select * from prod_db.prod_table where pin='ab\;xzh[Ge';
```

Comment: VK_217 It is not working. Same issue.. line 6:16 character '\' not supported here

Comment: @trougc try \\ instead of \

Comment: I tried \073 and it worked. I didn't check this. But I suppose this should also work. Thanks.